# I installed Ubuntu Gnome on my old Macbook Pro, now stuck with the grey screen at start

Tags: boot, system-installation, macbook

Installation worked perfectly, but when the computer rebooted, it stayed stuck on grey screen forever. any idea where the problem came from and how I can fix it?

Comment: It goes straight to grey screen, or does it show anything else first? I would just reinstall, unless it is not an option.

Comment: When I do a google search on this version it says its an old release that went out of support in April 2019 and built on a now non supported 16.04.

Comment: What are the specs of the computer? Which version of Ubuntu did you install?

Comment: Have you reset NV RAM?

Comment: Thank you guys for your answers. It goes straight to grey screen. Yesterday I tried also with Lubuntu and the problem i still here. Before that I choosed Ubuntu Gnome  because I read somewhere it is supposed working well on the 2011 Macbook pro.   About reseting Nvram, I just tried. It will reboot the computer, this time with the apple sound. I formated the whole harddrive, and installed Ubuntu or Lubuntu several times. But it finish to seteup the Os it ask to reboot. Then after the reboot it stay on grey screen. I think perhaps the problem come from the way the computer boot.

Comment: I have the same problem with my MacBook Pro 2011 and Ubuntu 21.04.

Answer (score 1):

The shim package causes this bug for older macs, which utilize an old EFI implementation (see [launchpad ticket](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/shim/+bug/1925010)).

It was fixed in a package update. **For me, it simply worked to tick "Download updates while installing Ubuntu" during the installation process of Ubuntu.** This installed the necessary update and fixed the problem for me.

Furthermore, a [workaround](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/shim/+bug/1925010/comments/2) exists.